# Why is task executing code before it finishes?

Tags: c#

I was looking to make a settings method that executes the given settings and than execute the passed function/task. So instead of me typing a settings method each time

```
pubic void SomeMethod()
{
    SettingsMethod()
    //code
    MainMethod()
}

public void SomeMethod2()
{
    SettingsMethod()
    /code...
    MainMethod()
}
```

i wanted to do something like this:

```
public async static Task<T> ConfigureSettings<T>(Task<T> apiCallMethod, string localHost,int port, string riotToken)
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://"+localHost + ":"+port);
            Console.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", riotToken);

            return await apiCallMethod;

        }

        public async static Task<string> GetSummonerId()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/lol-login/v1/session");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

And be able to call it like this:

```
 string summonerId = LeagueApiProcessor.ConfigureSettings(LeagueApiProcessor.GetSummonerId(), LeagueAccount.LocalHost, LeagueAccount.LocalHostPort, LeagueAccount.RiotToken).Result;
```

As i tried to debug the code, the

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/lol-login/v1/session");
```

is executing much earlier than the

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://"+localHost + ":"+port);
            Console.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress);
```

and that is making it crash each time.
I've tried changing the return types, but that just breaks my code even more. What would be the best approach to solve this, again this was my attempt to make a SettingsMethod() execute every time before the "MainMethod()" without having to type it in each function.

Comment: you are calling `ConfigureSettings` with the Task returned by `GetSummonerId`. the moment that Task is created (by calling the method), it _starts executing_. what you're seeing is perfectly fine and exactly the way i would expect this code do behave. i recommend refactoring your code so you don't confuse yourself

Comment: I understand what ur saying but can u give me a simple example of how should I try and refactor this. Because this was my attempt at refactoring an already bad looking code.

Comment: dont call the method on passing in just pass the function in and call it inside the configure function. the () tells the code to start executing so pass it in without it in your example call and do the getsummonerid call inside the configure method

Comment: Why pass the `Task` at all? Why not just call `ConfigureSettings` then `GetSummonerId`?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than accept an already running `Task<T>`, accept a `Func` that will start the `Task<T>` and return it *when you call it*. This can be as simple as:

```
public async static Task<T> ConfigureSettings<T>(Func<Task<T>> apiCallMethod, string localHost,int port, string riotToken)
    {
        //...

        return await apiCallMethod();

    }
```

And:

```
LeagueApiProcessor.ConfigureSettings(LeagueApiProcessor.GetSummonerId, ...
```

Notice that we're not *invoking* `GetSummonerId` when creating the arguments to `ConfigureSettings`, we're instead implicitly converting it to a delegate that is *called* at the end of `ConfigureSettings` instead.

For more complex examples (say, when you need to pass arguments to the second method), you may need to pass a lambda instead:

```
LeagueApiProcessor.ConfigureSettings(() => CallSomeTaskReturningMethod(arg1,arg2), ...
```